# What is the significance of the three phrases "was and is and is to come" and "is and was and is to come" and "was and is" in Revelation?

Tags: revelation

The phrase "who is and was and is to come" (ὁ ὢν καὶ ὁ ἦν καὶ ὁ ἐρχόμενος) first appears in Revelation 1:4. These terms are repeated in 1:8 and then again in 4:8 except the order is changed: "who was and is and is to come" (ὁ ἦν καὶ ὁ ὢν καὶ ὁ ἐρχόμενος). After this the initial phrase is used and repeated except "to come" has been omitted: "who is and was" (ὁ ὢν καὶ ὁ ἦν).

The arrangement throughout the book is chiastic:
[image]

Are all five passages referring to the same person? What significance should be attached to the unque order in 4:8? What does omitting "is to come" in the final two signify?

Comment: Let us note also that the middle term is deliberately negated in describing the beast- "was and is not and is to come" ch17 v8

Comment: It's the meaning of Gods name or the actual name itself

Answer (score 2):

What seems obvious is ὁ ἐρχόμενος already came in those passages.  11:17 is more obvious.

> 15 Then the seventh angel blew his trumpet, and there were loud voices in heaven, saying, “The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our Lord and of his Christ, and he shall reign forever and ever.”  (Rev. 11:15, ESV)

```
              “Just are you, O Holy One, who is and who was, 
  for you brought these judgments. 
        6       For they have shed the blood of saints and prophets, 
  and you have given them blood to drink. 
              It is what they deserve!”
```

> 7 And I heard the altar saying,

```
              “Yes, Lord God the Almighty, 
  true and just are your judgments!” (Rev. 16:5–7, ESV)
```

Answer (score 0):

**No Chiasm**

I fail to see the Chiastic pattern.  If anything, the first two are closely related; the 3rd and 5th are related but that is all.  I certainly do not see a relationship between the 1st and 5th, and between the 2nd and 4th.

Further, the very change in the titles lacking "to come" in the last two means that no chiasm can exist.

The identity of this person discussed is quite clear.

**Rev 1:4, 5 = The Father**

> (4) John to the seven churches that are in Asia: Grace to you and peace
> from Him who is, and who was, and who is to come, and from the seven
> spirits who are before His throne, (5) and from Jesus Christ, who is the faithful witness, the firstborn from the dead, and the ruler of the kings of the earth.

Note that there are three distinct entities here: (1) the One who is and who was and is to come (2) The seven Spirits (3) Jesus Christ

**Rev 1:8 = The Father**

> "I am the Alpha and the Omega," says the Lord God, "who is, and who
> was, and who is to come, the Almighty."

"Lord God" is a title never applied to Jesus but often applied to the Father such as Luke 1:32, Acts 3:22, Rev 15:3, 21:22, etc.  "Lord God Almighty" is applied frequently to the Father in the OT, Ps 59:5, 84:8, 89:8, Jer 38:17, 44:7, Amos 3:13, 5:16, 6:8, Hos 12:5, etc.

**Rev 4:8 = The Father**

> Day and night they never stop saying: "'Holy, holy, holy is the Lord
> God Almighty,' who was, and is, and is to come."

"Lord God" is a title never applied to Jesus but often applied to the Father such as Luke 1:32, Acts 3:22, Rev 15:3, 21:22, etc.  "Lord God Almighty" is applied frequently to the Father in the OT, Ps 59:5, 84:8, 89:8, Jer 38:17, 44:7, Amos 3:13, 5:16, 6:8, Hos 12:5, etc.

**Rev 11:17 = The Father**

> saying, “We give You thanks, Lord God, the Almighty, the One who is
> and who was, because You have taken Your great power and have begun to
> reign.

"Lord God" is a title never applied to Jesus but often applied to the Father such as Luke 1:32, Acts 3:22, Rev 15:3, 21:22, etc.  "Lord God Almighty" is applied frequently to the Father in the OT, Ps 59:5, 84:8, 89:8, Jer 38:17, 44:7, Amos 3:13, 5:16, 6:8, Hos 12:5, etc.

**Rev 16:5-7 = The Father**

**5** And I heard the angel of the waters say: “Righteous are You, O Holy One, who is and was, because You have brought these judgments. **6** For they have spilled the blood of saints and prophets, and You have given them blood to drink, as they deserve.” **7** And I heard the altar reply: “Yes, **Lord God Almighty**, true and just are Your judgments.”

See comments above about "Lord God Almighty" applying exclusively to the Father.

Further, "Lord God Almighty" is used as a title of the Father to distinguish Him from the Lamb is Rev 21:22 -

> I did not see a temple in the city, because the Lord God Almighty and
> the Lamb are its temple.

The title "Lord God Almighty" appears seven times in the NT - Rev 1:8, 4:8, 11:17, 15:3, 16:7, 19:6, 21:22, and always refers to the Father.  As stated above, this is a direct allusion to the often times in the OT where the same title is used of God, 2 Sam 5:10, Ps 80:19, Jer 5:14, 15:16, Zech 12:5, Amos 4:13, 5:14, 15, 6:14, 9:15, etc.

**"to Come"**

Of the five times the title "the One who was and is and is to come" occurs in Revelation, the last two do not have "to come" as listed by the OP.  I suggest that this precisely because we have the image in Rev 6:16 -

> and they said to the mountains and the rocks, “Fall on us and hide us
> from the sight of Him who sits on the throne, and from the wrath of
> the Lamb;

This verse is the culmination of the extended scene in Rev 4 & 5 where God the Father is described as seated on the throne and inaugurates the Jesus as the new King "on the right" of the apparently two-seater throne (Rev 5:1, 2).  Thus, when Jesus takes the throne as King, He does so beside the Father and we see Rev 6:16 that clearly depicts the second Advent as a scene with the Father and Son on the throne appearing and the wicked begging for destruction (contrast Isa 25:9).

Thus, it appears that in the images and sequence of the visions of Revelation, Rev 6:16 depicts the Father and Son as coming/arriving.  Thus, in Rev 11:17 and 16:5, the title of the Father does not need to include "to come" because He is recorded as having already come.

Comment: As Perry points out the obvious explanation for the omission of "is coming" is Christ **has** come. The expression is not simply was, is, and is, but is coming. You need to support your assertion that the revelation of Jesus Christ is that the Father is the one coming which must also be put into the context of Jesus Christ also coming. I believe you also have a "judgement" conundrum as your exegesis places judgement with the Father, not the Christ. I believe the NT is clear that Jesus Christ is the one coming to judge.

Comment: @RevelationLad - I explained that above about the double throne.  Next, John 8:15 Jesus says, "I judge no one", John 8:50, "And though I have no wish to glorify myself, God is going to glorify me. He is the true judge.", Rom 14;10 - For we will all stand before God's judgment seat.

Comment: The parallelism is with the order of the first two terms "is, was" which is maintained except with the one which is unique "was-is". You might strengthen your position by addressing why order is changed and then reverts back. For example, it is accurate to say the Word **was** with God and the Word who became flesh **is** with the Father. There is a physical reality and Biblical truth which follows the order. If the five all refer to the same one, then you should explain why the one which can be attributed to the Son must instead be given to the Father.